# iPod Nano 5th Gen Can't Disable Shake Gesture

Tags: multi-touch, ipod-nano

I have disabled the "shuffle on shake" feature of my iPod Nano 5th gen, yet occasionally this still happens.  I've noticed, for example, if I have it connected to the aux jack in my car while driving, if I hit a speedbump or pothole, it activates shuffle mode.  I've double-checked the setting to the point where I'm beginning to feel a bit OCD.  I know this is older hw, but is there some way to permanently disable this feature on my specific device?

Comment: The nano's shuffling is self-generated. Poor thing can't stop shivering at the thought of being replaced by the iPod touch you're trying to win. :D

Comment: Touché. Well played.

Comment: @AdamEberbach Can you please post that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, if you're going to vote it up (I like iPod touches too)

Comment: Come on, guys. You all know that this isn't a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a full restore of the iPod? I know it's kind of a last ditch thing to do, but it seems like you may be experiencing a hiccup in the hardware. Also, make sure you've got the latest update from Apple installed on it.